# How Do You Choose Whether To Use These, or Those, or The +Noun

Tags: word-choice

First of all, I know that there have been discussed a few threads on similar topic, but the threads didn't cover all my questions.

**How** do **you choose** **whether** to **use these**, or **those**, or **the +** **noun** **when posting replies** to the thread?

For instance, there are some random sentences, which I've just made:

*1) The first post*
Don't do it! If you do it, I'll be angry with you. 
Did you hear it? 
What? I didn't.

**What is the first answer supposed to be for the first post?** 
a) These sentences are wrong. — This would be my personal preference  
b) Those sentences are wrong. 
c) The sentences above are wrong. 
*(Note: These/those/the sentences above are intended to be 

Don't do it! If you do it, I'll be angry with you.
Did you hear it? What? I didn't.)*

*2) The first post* 
Don't do it! If you do it, I'll be angry with you. 
Did you hear it? What? I didn't.

*a) The first answer*
*These/those/the sentences are wrong. — I would choose these in this case. 
I don't know.
Bad things happen. 
*(Note: These/those/the sentences above intended to be
Don't do it! If you do it, I'll be angry with you.
Did you hear it? What? I didn't.)

*b) The second answer*
*These/those. — This time, I would choose either those or 'The sentences in the first post are wrong'.
Okay. I'll keep it in mind. 
Good bye. 
*(Note: These/those/'the sentences in the first post' are intended to be
Don't do it! If you do it, I'll be angry with you.
Did you hear it? What? I didn't.)

Answer (score 1):

According to me, 'these' is used for things that are near or in front of or when someone is talking for something that is in present.
For things that either happened in the past or are far or not in front of our eyes are referred to as 'those'.
'The' is used when we are talking about a singular thing. It may be in past or present.